# Execute Javascript coming from dojo.xhrGet in symfony

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony1, dojo

I am new to dojo and somewhat new to symfony as well and am having a wee problem here: I want to reload a part of my page using Ajax but it includes a Javascript which needs to be executed. This isn't reallly a problem in prototype or Jquery but I just can't figure it out in dojo. (I need to use dojo because it's a part of symfony and already in heavy use on the page I'm supposed to modify. I also know this is probably improped technique but it's just a little mod I need to do and this would be the easiest way ...)
Can you help??
Thanks,
thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using dojo's require tool

For more information regarding this, take a look at the documentation

```
dojo.require("my.path.to.file", false, true);
```

Call this when you want to load the javascript file, mostly after the ajax request is complete. So that if this javascript is to alter/perform some operations on the ajax loaded content placed into DOM, you won't get NOT_FOUND dom exception.

Comment: I thought dojo.require() was for dojo modules? To clarify: I want to execute the inline script in the html that's being reloaded by Ajax ...